# PHP Check if a string has at least two specific words in it

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm using `preg_match` to check if a string has a specific word in it:

```
$string = 'This string contains a few words that are in an array!';
$arr = ['string', 'few', 'words'];

if(preg_match('['.implode('|', $arr).']', $string)){
    //do something if there is at least one word from the array inside that string
}
```

This is working quite nice but it will return true if there is at least one word and i need it to return true if there are at least two words from the array inside that string.

Can that be done in one step? If not, which way should i go from here to obtain that result?

Thank you!:D

Comment: Try `preg_match('~\b(?:'.implode('|', $arr).')\b.*\b(?:'.implode('|', $arr).')\b~', $string)`

Comment: Try `substr_count` http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Comment: hey @MA, but how do i use `substr_count` for multiple needles(and case insensitive) :-s. For example i want to check `string: This is mine and yours` for `arr: is, and` so if `is` and `and` are found in that string it will return true :-s

Comment: hey @WiktorStribiżew can you please help me understand what is going on there? :-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use preg_match_all for this

```
$string = 'This string contains a few words that are in an array!';
$arr = ['string', 'few', 'words'];
$count = preg_match_all('['.implode('|', $arr).']', $string); // Returns 3
```

Comment: Except that if the string contains `'This string contains a string'` it will also return 2 as there are 2 `string` words. But it does not contain at least 2 of the words you are looking for it just finds `string` twice

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is to know that **at least 2** of the required words exist in the string then you need to be careful. If you have 2 of the same words in the string it is easy to get a false positive if you just use `preg_match_all` to search for occurances.

This will report 3 i.e. all 3 words are present in the haystack

```
$string = 'This string contains a string and a few other words!';
$finds = ['string', 'few', 'words'];
$findCount = 0;

foreach ($finds as $find) {
    if ( strpos($string, $find) !== false ) $findCount++;
}
echo $findCount;
```

It will report 2 if you use this string

```
$string = 'This string contains a string and a other words!';
```

And most importantly report only **ONE** if you use this string which contains the word `string` twice, but not 2 of the required words.

```
$string = 'This string contains a string and other stuff!';
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is fine if you don't care exact match. If you want to match EXACT word then you need to use word boundary `\b`.

Here is the example:

```
$arr = ['string', 'few', 'words'];

preg_match_all('#\b('.implode('|', $arr).')\b#', $string, $wordsFound);

$wordsFound = array_unique($wordsFound[0]);

if(count($wordsFound) >= 2){
    echo "Matched";
}else{
    echo "Not matched";
}


Input: $string = 'This string contains a few words that are in an array!';
Output: Matched (3 founds)

Input: $string = 'This string222 contains a few words that are in an array!';
Output: Matched (2 founds)

Input: $string = 'This string222 contains a few23 words that are in an array!';
Output: Not Matched (1 found)

Input: $string = 'This string contains a string words that are in an array!';
Output: Matched (2 founds)

Input: $string = 'This string contains a string string that are in an array!';
Output: Not Matched (1 found)
```

Comment: This has a probelm if the string is `A string and a string`

Comment: @RiggsFolly code updated. Now it will check unique value